# How to save a file to iCloud Drive from my ios app?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

What do I need to do for my app to save a file to iCloud? I have added the iCloud capability in the Signing & Capabilities.  However, I don't understand what permissions I need to put in the info.plist file.

I created a UIActivityController and send it a URL of the file.  Then when I click on Save To Files I see the option to save to iCloud but it's dimmed.  Please see screenshots. [Save To Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaS3C.jpg) [iCloud Dimmed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkKUC.png)

[image]

[image]

Here is my code:

```
let fileURL = folderUrl.appendingPathComponent(self.crapsSession.fileName).appendingPathExtension("csv")
                        
let items = [fileURL]
let ac = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: items, applicationActivities: nil)
self.present(ac, animated: true)
```

I've searched all over the internet but couldn't figure out what to do.  Thanks for helping a noob.

Comment: Can you save the file to iCloud Drive in other apps on the same device?

Comment: Thanks for helping.  The screenshot is from the simulator.  When I loaded to a real device, the iCloud option is no longer dimmed.

Comment: it's because you probably didn't login to iCloud in your simulator.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I just signed into iCloud in the simulator.  It works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping. The screenshot is from the simulator. When I loaded to a real device, the iCloud option is no longer dimmed.